# Conversion of Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to convert the following Data Frame

[image]

to this

[image]

I am able to accomplish this in the following way:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"D:\Python_Test\df_test.csv")

df1=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Country","Region"], values="Value",columns="Type").reset_index()
df_c=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by="Country")["Value"].agg("sum")).rename(columns={"Value":"Country_Value"}).reset_index()
df_r=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by="Region")["Value"].agg("sum")).rename(columns={"Value":"Region_Value"}).reset_index()

df_final= pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df_c,how="inner",on="Country"),df_r,how="inner",on="Region")
```

Is there a better/simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and for `pivot_table` is added `aggfunc='sum'` for change default aggregation `mean`:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"D:\Python_Test\df_test.csv")

df_final=(df.pivot_table(index=["Country","Region"], 
                    values="Value",
                    columns="Type", 
                    aggfunc='sum')
       .reset_index())

df_final['Country_Value'] = df_final.groupby(by="Country")["Value"].transform("sum")
df_final['Region_Value'] = df_final.groupby(by="Region")["Value"].transform("sum")

print (df_final)
```

Comment: This will work only if groupby has same number of entries as pivot, but group by has 12 rows and pivot has 6 rows.

Comment: `This will work only if groupby has same number of entries as pivot` - Not understand, first is used `pivot` and then for `df1` is aggregate `sum` to new columns in `df1`. So after `transform` all working perfectly.

Comment: @KVHP - Or you forget change `agg` to `transform` ?

Comment: I have used your code only, but it did not work. Instead I have used the transform to manipulate the actual dataframe and applied the pivot

Comment: @KVHP - Can you add wrong output from my code with your data to question?

Comment: @KVHP - Maybe help if rename `df1` to `df_final`.